# How to create custom filter on ng-repeat array? [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to filter json, here is my html:

```
<span  style="margin-top: 8px;" ng-repeat="(key, val) in task.depencies | jsonFilter">
<%val.name%> From: <%val.start_date | dateFilter | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'%> To: <%val.end_date | dateFilter | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'%>, 
</span>
```

And here is my filter:

```
filter('jsonFilter', jsonFilter);

function jsonFilter()
{

    return function (input) {
        input = angular.fromJson(input);
        return input;
};
```

So I need to filter this: `task.depencies` and then send trought ng-repeat.

Comment: You may want to try `<span ... ng-repeat="(key, val) in (task.depencies | jsonFilter)">` (note the parentheses).

Comment: I get this error ` Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…return%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%2214%2F01%2F2016%22%7D%5D%5D`

Comment: so, what's the problem? if you need this task done - propose a work for some freelancer. if you have already something and there is an error - post it here and somebody will eventually help you.